# Google Sheets IMPORTXML not working for YouTube URLs

Tags: regex, web-scraping, google-sheets, youtube, google-query-language

I'm looking to extract the video title or video description from YouTube videos in Google Sheets. I have the URL and when I write the `IMPORTXML` formula, it keeps just showing me "Share your videos with friends, family, and the world" for the description and only "YouTube" if I change it to the title.  Has something changed on YouTube's side?

Example:
`=IMPORTXML(F3,"//meta[@name='description']/@content")`

Cell F3 contains value: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cwttM41xVBY`

Output from formula:
`Share your videos with friends, family, and the world`

Comment: Also, this seems to be only with youtube URLs, other sites seem to be pulling in the description just fine

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA(A1)), 
 "where Col1 starts with 'title:""'", 0), """(.*)""")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  this looks to have worked.  Do you know how I would modify this if I also want to pull the description of the video?

Comment: @Tai unfortunately, description is scattered all over so this approach is not ideal for that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPgRI.png